# Python Strings with backslash

Tags: python, string, escaping

I want to define a string like below:

```py
text = 'sample\)'
```

As shown I want to preserve the whole string including backslash and every character after that. But the problem is, this constant converts to `'sample\\)'` . This constant is not for printing purposes, but to be used to construct a string with more values.

Any help?

Comment: The extra backslash is an escape character. It does not actually exist in the string. What's the actual issue you're having? Show your code.

Answer (score 1):

The `'\\'` is just how Python is displaying it so that you can see that the backslash is an actual backslash and not part of an escape sequence.  However, as you can see if you `print` it, the string really is just `'sample'` followed by a backslash and a close parenthesis.

To confirm this, look at `len(text)` and confirm that it's 8.

That being said, you should be more explicit with your use of backslashes.  In this case, Python is figuring out what you really want because `'\)'` is not a valid escape sequence.  However, had you done, say, `'sample\n'`, you wouldn't have a literal backslash in your string.

To be explicit, you can either escape the backslash

```py
text = 'sample\\)'
```

or use a raw string

```py
text = r'sample\)'
```

Python won't do any escaping with raw strings.

Comment: I'm generating a password using this variable to connect to a FTP service. That's the issue I'm having. The password has a backslash.

Comment: And you have a backslash in your string.  What's the problem?